# Помогите с HTML, CSS, копирование текста нажатием на блок

Tags: html, css

Блок внутри которого еще 4 блока, наведя на один из них появляется текст, нужно сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на появившийся текст он копировался в буфер.

```css
.block-palitra{
    min-height: 240px;
    margin: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #2c2c2c;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.block-palitra1{
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    min-height: 90px;
    padding: 2px 10px;
}
.block-palitra2{
    min-height: 70px;
    padding: 2px 10px;
}
.block-palitra3{
    min-height: 50px;
    padding: 2px 10px;
}
.block-palitra4{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    min-height: 30px;
    padding: 2px 10px;
}
.blocking{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color: white;
    display:none;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 120px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.block-palitra1:hover .blocking{
    display:block;
}
.block-palitra2:hover .blocking{
    display:block;
}
.block-palitra3:hover .blocking{
    display:block;
}
.block-palitra4:hover .blocking{
    display:block;
}
.nav-link-transition{
    transition: opacity 10s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-palitra">                       
    <div class="block-palitra1" style="background-color: #f0f5f9">        <div class="blocking">#f0f5f9</div></div>
    <div class="block-palitra2" style="background-color: #c9d6df">        <div class="blocking">#c9d6df</div></div>
    <div class="block-palitra3" style="background-color: #52616b">        <div class="blocking">#52616b</div></div>
    <div class="block-palitra4" style="background-color: #1e2022"><div class="blocking">#1e2022</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, вам нужно это:

```js
function copytext(element) {
  var range, selection;
  if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(element);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = window.getSelection();
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(element);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
  //console.log(range);
  try {
    document.execCommand("copy");
    alert("Скопировано в буфер обмена: " + selection);
  } catch (err) {
    alert("Невозможно скопировать текст");
  }
}
```

```css
.block-palitra {
  min-height: 240px;
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #2c2c2c;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.block-palitra1 {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  min-height: 90px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.block-palitra2 {
  min-height: 70px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.block-palitra3 {
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.block-palitra4 {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  min-height: 30px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.blocking {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: white;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 120px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.block-palitra1:hover .blocking {
  display: block;
}

.block-palitra2:hover .blocking {
  display: block;
}

.block-palitra3:hover .blocking {
  display: block;
}

.block-palitra4:hover .blocking {
  display: block;
}

.nav-link-transition {
  transition: opacity 10s linear;
}

textarea {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-palitra">
  <div class="block-palitra1" style="background-color: #f0f5f9">
    <div class="blocking" onclick="copytext(this)">#f0f5f9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-palitra2" style="background-color: #c9d6df">
    <div class="blocking" onclick="copytext(this)">#c9d6df</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-palitra3" style="background-color: #52616b">
    <div class="blocking" onclick="copytext(this)">#52616b</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-palitra4" style="background-color: #1e2022">
    <div class="blocking" onclick="copytext(this)">#1e2022</div>
  </div>
</div>

<textarea name="result" cols="40" rows="3" placeholder="Проверить"></textarea>
```

Comment: да, спасибо большое

Comment: @Sevastopol', я тоже попытался реализовать, не получилось, но теперь мучает вопрос. Если переделать block-palitra1-4 в кнопки, а blocking-в input, то можно ли каким-либо образом собрать все input через делегирование?